# DB2 connection in SSIS package

Tags: ssis, db2

if I  run ssis package for one task I getting  the following error for DB2 connection [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000

Comment: please can anyone answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ADO.net connection instead of ODBC connection it worked for me.